# Не возможно выбрать значения в ComboBox из SQL запроса

Tags: c#, oracle, combobox

При попытке вывести список значений в ComboBox из запроса к БД Oracle, выходит ошибка запроса:

> -2147467259 - Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleErrorCollection

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess версия 4.122.18.3

Сам блок с кодом:

```
public static class Setting
    {
        public static string ora_connect = "User Id=***;Password=***;Data Source=***";
        public static string ora_street = "SELECT STREET, trim(NAME) NAME from address;";
    }

private void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(Setting.ora_connect);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(Setting.ora_street, connection);
            OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
            OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            data.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            data.Columns.Add("Streets", typeof(Int32));
            data.Load(reader);
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Streets";
            comboBox1.DataSource = data.DefaultView;
            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
        }
        catch (OracleException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка запроса!");
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ErrorCode + " - " + ex.Errors);
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Хорошо бы всё в using'и обернуть. | adapter никак не используется. Нужно либо выкинуть его, либо с его помощью заполнять дататейбл: adapter.Fill и тогда можно выкинуть reader.

Comment: Да. Заметил что adapter не используется. Убрал совсем. @alexander-petrov не совсем понял об обёртке в using - я только учусь и могу где-то неверно писать код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился:
Убрал точку с запятой из запроса

> "SELECT STREET, trim(NAME) NAME from address";